# How to compare initialize string?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am having trouble comparing the initialize string in my homework.. This is just a sample code and I am having problem why with the output...

Enter your answer: Cucumber
Your Answer is: Cucumber

Cucumber is the correct answer

But it display: 
You got the wrong answer 
I really dont how I can fix it

```
 Data Segment      
  input db "Enter Your Answer: $"
  g db 20 dup('$') ;
  strlen1 db $-g
  str2 db 'cucumber','$'
  strlen2 db $-str2
  streq db 10,13,'You got the correct answer','$'
  struneq db 10,13,'You got the Wrong answer','$'
Data Ends
Code Segment
  Assume cs:code, ds:data
  Begin:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax    
   mov ah,09h
   lea dx,input
   int 21h    
   MOV AH,0AH
   MOV DX,SI
   INT 21H     
   lea si,g
   lea di, str2
   mov cx, 3
   mov al, strlen1
   mov bl, strlen2
   cmp al, bl
   jne Not_Equal
   repe cmpsb
   jne Not_Equal
   jmp Equal
   Not_Equal:
       mov ah, 09h
       lea dx, struneq
       int 21h
       jmp Exit
   Equal:
       mov ah, 09h
       lea dx, streq
       int 21h
   Exit:
       mov ax, 4c00h
       int 21h
Code Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the string lengths statically from the data in the data segment. One of them is 20 bytes and the other one is "cucumber$" which is way shorter.
You need to get the input length from the DOS call you are using for input. I have never used 16 bit DOS myself but [this site](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) offers a reference on what you get back from the call.
As you can see the buffer returned doesn't start with the actual data so you have to start reading from a few bytes further into the buffer.
Also, you get the length from there which is what you need.

Also keep in mind that repe repeats cx times so it should be set to a string length (use strlen1 because strlen2 will include carriage return). Right now it is set to 3.

I hope this helps.

Edit: The input buffer passed to the call is in DX.
You are putting g into it at first but then you are overwriting it with si somehow.

Comment: Is there anyway you can fix my code?, Im still new in assembly

Comment: I would start by fixing the actual input code. If you look at the reference I linked to the first byte should be the maximum number of characters to read, the second byte... just something for now; the call will fill that with the input length. The rest of the buffer will be your actual string. So you can either treat the first two bytes of g as size data or reserve two additional bytes before it for that.  You can verify this by printing out the string you read first. Of course there is a lot to learn but good luck. :-)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.fysnet.net/kbbuffio.htm) helps. The data segment is at the end of the code here in case you are wondering.